# How to store organic cold press sunflower oil for long term usage?

Tags: storage-method, oil, organic

I have opened the bottle and I will be using very little amount daily. 
It is not going to be finished soon.

What are the storage instructions?  Should be stored in fridge?

Answer (score -1):

Keep it sealed and in the dark. It will last for a long time so long as it doesn't get contaminated.

Do NOT put in the fridge, it will get ruined overnight.

Comment: Why no fridge? Details, please...

Comment: Well I looked it up and some oils "can" be stores in the fridge, but I have over and over again seen oil put in the fridge and bloom a cloud. Even when you take it out, it just keeps growing until it fills the whole bottle. In the winter I have seen it on the shelves at the grocery store too. Whole Isles of oil gone bad cause it was in the cold too long. I never put oil in the fridge, and keep it in my cabinets.

Comment: Oils can become hazy upon refrigeration; once they are allowed to reach normal room temperature, the haze will dissipate. It does not harm oil to keep it in the refrigerator, if anything the shelf life is extended by refrigeration.

Comment: Sorry not what I've seen, and have seen whole isles gone bad in the winter. I wish I took a picture now that we're talking about it